# Redis fetch records from hash that match key and wild card hashKey?

Tags: redis, hashtable

I have a hash table who's key looks like so

```
geo:a
```

The hashKey looks like so

```
NAME:USERS_IP
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to fetch all the values for NAME where the USERS_IP is a wild card *. The table will have millions of records so I don't want to fetch everything an then have to parse it with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) is your friend here with the `MATCH` option set to `NAME:*`. For example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET 'geo:a' 'alice jones:10.123.8.9' 'some_val'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET 'geo:a' 'bill jones:192.123.8.9' 'some_val'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET 'geo:a' 'bill jones:192.89.89.89' 'some_val'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSCAN 'geo:a'  0 match "bill jones:*"
1) "0"
2) 1) "bill jones:192.123.8.9"
   2) "some_val"
   3) "bill jones:192.89.89.89"
   4) "some_val"
```